# figuring out Maximum ID in table

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions, max, auto-increment

I'm trying to figure out the highest id number (set to 'auto_increment') in my table, I tried

```
SELECT * FROM  `mytable` WHERE MAX( `id` )
```

but get

```
#1305 - FUNCTION xymplydb01.MAX does not exist
```

Is there any other way how I can get this without using max?
Thanks!
Ron

Comment: please specify your sql tool and its version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldnt the MAX be in the select clause and not the where clause:

```
SELECT MAX('id') as id from 'mytable'
```

I didnt think using the MAX function in the where clause was valid.

Or if you want the row of data you could do a sub-query as well:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 'mytable' 
WHERE id=(
    SELECT max('id') FROM 'mytable'
)
```

or without using MAX at all

```
Select * from 'mytable' order by 'id' desc limit 1
```

This would grab the largest id and only return that row.

Answer (score 2):

Use this syntax instead:

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM mytable;
```